# Uploading a file to Marketo using a Dropbox link to the file

Tags: python, api, https, dropbox, marketo

I am using the python code below to upload a file to our marketing automation tool Marketo. It works when I have the file downloaded locally (/home/tyron/Downloads/yoda.jpeg) but I would like to be able to upload a file straight from Dropbox to Marketo without having to download it inbetween because I will be hosting this code in Zapier.

What is the best way to do this upload when given a link to the dropbox file?

```
import requests

url = "xxxxxx/rest/asset/v1/files.json"

payload = {'name': 'test',
'file': '/home/tyron/Downloads/yoda.jpe',
'folder': '{"id":367,"type":"Folder"}'}
files = [
  ('file', open('/home/tyron/Downloads/yoda.jpeg','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer yyyyyyyy'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I can help with questions about Dropbox itself, but I don't have context on Marketo. Does the Marketo API allow you to specify files by a URL? (You'll probably want to check their documentation or reach out to them for help with that.) If it does though, you can get a URL to a file's content from the Dropbox API via [the /2/files/get_temporary_link endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link) and supply that to Marketo.

Comment: Thanks Greg, that is what I was looking for. I'll follow up with Marketo to check that the API accepts URLs and if they do it looks like the temporary endpoint should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Greg's suggestion in the comments I was able to upload the file to Marketo using the temporary link endpoint from dropbox.

Python Code to Get Dropbox Endpoint

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import unquote
import requests
import json

link = "https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Telnyx/...../file"

path  = urlparse(link).path
path = re.search("(/Telnyx.*$)",path).group(0).lower()
path = unquote(path)

print(path)

url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_temporary_link"
payload = {"path": path}

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(payload))

print(response)

link = re.search('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', response.text).group(0)

return {'id': 1234, 'rawHTML': link}
```

Python Code to Upload to Marketo

```
import requests
import urllib
import json
import re


path = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/......." #returned from previous function

f = urllib.request.urlopen(path)
mime_type = f.info().get_content_type()

f_ext = f.info().get_content_type().split("/")[1]

url = "https://xxx-xxx-xxx.mktorest.com/rest/asset/v1/files.json"

f_name = 'Name.' + f_ext

payload = {
'folder': '{"id":xxxx","type":"Folder"}'
}

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxx'
}

files = {'file': (f_name, f, mime_type)}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
f_url = re.search('"url":"(.*)","folder',response.text).group(1)

return {'id': 1234, 'rawHTML': f_url}
```